# How to launch a gui program in i3 without tiling?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to run a graphical program on i3 window manager but it's automatically sized then put on the split screen when I launch it :

```
$ source my_gui
```

How to obtain a floating window directly in i3 without use the keybord shortcut *Alt+Ctrl+Space* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to start an application as floating, but you can create a rule which to tell i3 it should be in floating mode. You can create rules based on x properties like class. If your window has "MyApp" as WM_CLASS you can use `for_window [class="MyApp"] floating enable`. Of course you can also use different properties.

For more information see also [this i3 faq](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/61/forcing-windows-as-always-floating/) and the i3 documentation, e.g. [this part about criterias](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_criteria).

Answer (score 1):

Get the name of the window with `xprop` :

```
WM_NAME(STRING) = "MyApp - ItsWindow"
(...)
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "myapp", "MyApp"
```

And then, in your `config` file:

```
for_window [class="(?i)myapp" title="(?i)MyApp - ItsWindow"] floating enable
```